# Replace 44 to 0 in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database

How to replace first 44 digits to 0 in MySQL?

For example:

4476384424131 to 076384424131

Comment: Your example has nowhere near 44 digits. ;-) Use the replace function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using character types and [substring functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substr), you can simply cut off the initial '44' and replace it with a zero concatenated back on.

```
UPDATE tbl
  SET num = CONCAT('0', SUBSTR(num, 3))
WHERE LEFT(num, 2) = '44'
```

(Edit: fixed the WHERE clause to use `LEFT()` instead of `SUBSTR()`)

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT('0', SUBSTR(4476384424131, 3));
+-----------------------------------------+
| CONCAT('0', SUBSTR(4476384424131, 3))   |
+-----------------------------------------+
| 076384424131                            |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: @user The substring position.  `SUBSTR(num, 3)` returns everything starting with the 3rd character, so everything after the 44